# Rails Devise gem -> Authenticate a webservice call without user login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, authentication, devise, rubygems

My rails application is Devise gem for user login/authentication. I need to use a webservice call to retrieve data for manipulation. Can someone suggest how this can be done without having to use front end login?
I need some way of authenticating the web service call

SOLUTION->
I ended up using 
https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

Another option is
https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, devise use to include something called token authentication, but it was inheritely insecure and it got removed. The removed code and a better alternative was published in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) by one of devise's team members and later written into a gem, [devise-token_authenticatable](https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable), by someone else.

Simply put, you will store a authentication token in the users, and ask for both their email and token on each request to see if they match, but compare it securely. It's common not to store the user in session for this request.

Comment: Thanks, Leito. I have been checking the gem you mentioned. But it doesn't seem to migrate the database.

Comment: Simply add a string called authentication_token to the users table. That's all the migration you need. For example see how they do it in their spec's app: https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable/blob/d02b9754db13552b3ad55283330ebf343b788763/spec/support/rails_app/db/migrate/20100401102949_create_tables.rb#L36

Comment: Leito, I added 2 new columns to the User table and I don't get any errors anymore. But what https/http call do I make? I don't see an example. Something like-> https://mysite?email=123@test.com&authentication_token=werewr

Comment: In the gist I shared, see _safe_token_authentication.rb_ (https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6#file-2_safe_token_authentication-rb) it has the code that implements what I told you before. Provide both email and auth_token, find by email and securely compare the user's token with the provided token.In this case they use the params, but you could use HTTP headers too. Also the gem comes with a Warden strategy that allows to use HTTP basic auth: https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise/token_authenticatable/strategy.rb

Comment: please pardon my ignorance, but I checked the code from the gist you mentioned. Am I to add that code to my application_controller.rb? That didn't work i.e. the page always pushes the code to sign_in.

Comment: Leito, I got what I needed and got it to work. Thank you for all your help

Comment: I'm glad you figure it out, it makes for a better learning experience! Please consider using the gem rather than your own implementation of the code provided on the gist. You will benefit from having less code to maintain on your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own session create method and override the one that comes with devise. First inside your router you would customize devise

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: "sessions"}
```

Then you can implement this with your own controller and inherit from Devise::SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    self.resource = AuthService.perform(auth_options) # do the custom check here with your service call
    sign_in(resource_name, resource) #this will set the devise session and login the user
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

That should give you a way to have your own custom logic for creating session. Also have a look at github implementation:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Hope it helps